# How to enlarge and then, split an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to enlarge the following image and then split it into 2 parts in order to be printable on a A4 paper.

Sorry, I uploaded it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtb0ugfo0rk6aq8/corr_matrix0.png?dl=0) because it is a little bigger than 2 MiB.

Also, I added it's [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/13u6u4raxkonomm/corr_matrix0.pdf?dl=0) file

It should be noted that A4 paper margins are: Top: 3cm, Bottom: 3cm, Left: 3, and Right: 4.

Please accept my apology if it is a simple question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ot wont get meaninfully better than just printing it as it is now.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks. Sorry but If it is not possible to print it on 2 A4 papers, on what kind of paper it would be better to print it on?

Comment: Professional printers would be able to do large scale printing without the need to print to multiple A4's. But if you're printing at home or the office or whatever, Adobe Acrobat has that [tile feature in the print dialog](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-posters-banners-acrobat-reader.html). There's also [Posterazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/), which is made for this exact purpose. It makes it really easy.

Comment: @Joonas Thanks a lot for your time and consideration. I provided it as pdf file, too. I need it would be printed as some part of my thesis, so that's why I want to print it on multiple A4 papers. However, If I save it as pdf, I don't know how to set margins nor to add page numbers. Really, I am plotting it via this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997662/how-to-plot-heatmap-for-high-dimensional-dataset Thanks.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks a lot for your time and consideration. I provided it as pdf file, too.

Comment: I don't see why the two methods I mentioned wouldn't work. Why is pdf an issue when it comes to page numbers or margins? You could convert it to a jpeg if you feel that helps. The only issue I can see with any automatic method is that you can't really choose where it splits it, so you'll likely end up cutting some boxes half.

Comment: @Joonas If I use the first method, it would end up with some pages with the same number. However, I need different page number for each page. Besides, page numbers after this shape also would be affected so, I couldn't use the first method.

Answer (score 2):

The image is already good enough quality for printing. At 300dpi the print size would be 24"x18". It certainly doesn't need to be enlarged!

The image size is 7200px x 5400px.  Dividing by 300dpi gives 24 x 18 inches (or 609mm x 457mm).

To print it on one sheet, it would fit on something like an A1 sheet (594 x 841 mm), then you could trim it to size. A large format inkjet printer could print it.  Such prints are inexpensive.  I'd go down that route if I were you.

As for the second part of the question, images can be split or cropped in virtually any raster image editing software, such as Photoshop or free software like GIMP. While it's entirely possible to cut up the image to fit on 2 A4 sheets, it would make the writing pretty small and difficult to read.

Comment: There are 7688 blueish squares, everyone have a number. Can you read those numbers?

Comment: @user287001 - yes if you [view them at 100%](https://i.imgur.com/LS051E1.png), they are certainly readable.

Comment: Although again if they were vectors they would print even better

Comment: ok. The browser doesn't show them. Thanks for the rectification.

Comment: @user287001 Thanks a lot for your time and consideration. I provided it as pdf file, too.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks a lot for your time and consideration. I upvote your informative answer.

Comment: @ebrahimi - The PDF you have is vector, so this can be printed as large as you want without degradation in quality.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks a lot. I need to split the pdf into some parts and then, print it on A4 paper. It should be mentioned that each part should have it's own page number when it is inserted to the word document. Could you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: @ebrahimi - I've no idea. I don't use MS Word. Sorry about that.  I think Adobe Reader has a function for tiling prints. It's explained here: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-posters-banners-acrobat-reader.html